# Проблема с вектором в C++

Tags: c++, строки, классы, указатели, память

Есть вот такой класс Student.

```
class Student
{
public:
    Student(){}

    Student(const Student &student) {
        firstName = student.firstName;
        secondName = student.secondName;
        patronymic = student.patronymic;
        dateOfBirth = student.dateOfBirth;
        address = student.address;
        number = student.number;
        faculty = student.faculty;
        course = student.course;
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        delete firstName;
        delete secondName;
        delete patronymic;
        delete dateOfBirth;
        delete address;
        delete number;
        delete faculty;
        delete course;
    }
    void setFirstName(std::string *firstName) {
        this->firstName = firstName;
    }

    void setSecondName(std::string *secondName) {
        this->secondName = secondName;
    }

    void setPatronymic(std::string *patronymic) {
        this->patronymic = patronymic;
    }

    void setDateOfBirth(std::string *dateOfBirth) {
        this->dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    void setAddress(std::string *address) {
        this->address = address;
    }

    void setNumber(std::string *number) {
        this->number = number;
    }

    void setFaculty(std::string *faculty) {
        this->faculty = faculty;
    }

    void setCourse(std::string *course) {
        this->course = course;
    }

    std::string getFirstName() {
        return *firstName;
    }

    std::string getSecondName() {
        return *secondName;
    }

    std::string getPatronymic() {
        return *patronymic;
    }

    std::string getDateOfBirth() {
        return *dateOfBirth;
    }

    std::string getAddress() {
        return *address;
    }

    std::string getNumber() {
        return *number;
    }

    std::string getFaculty() {
        return *faculty;
    }

    std::string getCourse() {
        return *course;
    }

    std::string show() {
        std::string comma = ", ";
        return *secondName + comma + *firstName + comma + *patronymic +
               comma + *dateOfBirth + comma + *address + comma + *number + comma +
               *faculty + comma + *course + ". ";
    }


private:

    std::string *firstName = new std::string;
    std::string *secondName = new std::string;
    std::string *patronymic = new std::string;
    std::string *dateOfBirth = new std::string;
    std::string *address = new std::string;
    std::string *number = new std::string;
    std::string *faculty = new std::string;
    std::string *course = new std::string;


};
```

При создание вектора этого класса вот таким образом и вставкой в конец экземпляра этого класса, вылетает ошибка -1073741819;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<Student> vector;
    vector.push_back(Student());
}
```

Но вот таким образом всё отрабатывает нормально.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<Student*> vector;
    vector.push_back(new Student());
}
```

В чём причина такого поведения?

Comment: Ваш класс состоит из диких утечек памяти и нарушений Правила Трех. Это бессмысленно править. Все - ффтопку и начните сначала. Перестаньте использовать указатели в качестве полей класса. Откуда возникла такая идея? Почему поля класса вдруг стали указателями и создаются через `new`???

Comment: @AnT, вот утечек я тут как раз не вижу. Наоборот освобождается то, что не должно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Утечки в `set...`

Comment: @Qwertiy: Конструктор копирования - пулеметная очередь утечек памяти. Обратите внимание на инициализаторы с `new` прямо в объявлениях полей в теле класса - все эти `new` станут утечками в конструкторе копирования, т.к. исходные значения указателей будут "перетерты" новыми значениями.

Comment: @AnT, а, точно. Впрочем, если исправить как я думал по типу `*address = *student.address;`, то утечки устранятся, как и в set.

Comment: @Qwertiy, или `*address = student.address;`? Ведь student - ссылка..

Comment: @Александр, нет. Ведь address - указатель. `*student.address` - это `*(student.address)` (а вот `(*student).address` - то же самое что `student->address`), т. е. мы разыменовываем свой указатель, получаем ссылку на строку, разыменовываем чужой указатель, и одной строке присваиваем другую копированием содержимого (и не меняя указатели).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас полно полей типа

```
std::string *address = new std::string;
std::string *number = new std::string;
```

т.е. адреса, указывающие на некоторое место в памяти.

В деструкторе вы их удаляете.

Но ведь в конструкторе копирования вы копируете эти адреса:

```
Student(const Student &student) {
    ...
    address = student.address;
    number = student.number;
```

Значит, при удалении а оригинала, и копии, вы будете **дважды** удалять одну и ту же память.

Что категорически противопоказано. Поищите, что такое *глубокое копирование*. Вы должны копировать не указатели, а то, на что они указывают...

Но вообще говоря, это не единственная ваша ошибка. Например, у вас нет оператора присваивания, в функциях типа

void setFaculty(std::string *faculty) {
        this->faculty = faculty;
    }

вы не освобождаете старую память (что ведет к утечкам).

Не вижу вообще ни малейшего смысла в ваших указателях на `string` - просто работайте со строками, будет проще и надежнее - не с

```
std::string *address = new std::string;
std::string *number = new std::string;
```

а с

```
std::string address;
std::string number;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Конструктор копирования копирует указатели, а потом оба объекта их удаляют в деструкторе.
2. Та же проблема с методами set*.
3. В коде с указателями в векторе деструкторы студентов вообще не вызываются.
4. В этом классе вообще нет смысла держать указатели, замени на нормальные строки.